# Excel.Interop.Chart.Export does not close exported image file

Tags: c#, excel

I have made a small class that takes an excel workbook, graps the contained charts in the workbook and export each of them to PNG files.

It almost works fine, but I have a problem regarding the generated PNG files, the class doesn't close the files properly, until the user closes the application.

Here is my class:

```
        public List<string> ExportCharts(string fileName)
    {
        var exportedGraphsList = new List<string>();

        Excel.Workbooks xlWorkBooks = null;
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook = null;
        Excel.Application xlApp = null;
        Excel.Sheets xlSheets = null;
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        try
        {
            xlApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
            xlWorkBooks = xlApp.Workbooks;
            xlWorkBook = xlWorkBooks.Open(fileName);
            xlSheets = xlWorkBook.Charts;

            foreach (Excel.Chart xlChart in xlSheets)
            {
                var exportfileName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["imageSavePath"] + @"\" + xlChart.Name + ".png";                                      
                xlChart.Export(exportfileName, "PNG", misValue);
                exportedGraphsList.Add(exportfileName);
            }

            return exportedGraphsList;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + "\n\n" + ex.StackTrace, "Der gik noget galt");
            exportedGraphsList.Clear();
            return exportedGraphsList;
        }
        finally
        {
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

            if(xlSheets != null)
                Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(xlSheets);

            if (xlWorkBook != null)
            {
                xlWorkBook.Close(false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
                Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(xlWorkBook);
            }

            if (xlWorkBooks != null)
                Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(xlWorkBooks);

            if (xlApp != null)
            {
                xlApp.Quit();
                Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(xlApp);
            }
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    }
```

When this method is invoked, it starts and closes the Excel proces very nicely, but the PNG files remains open. I could of coruse put a timestamp on the exported filesnames, but I fear it will confuse the user.

Thanks in advance for any hints or ideas. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved - it was due to the fact that I loaded the image files afterwards to the GUI.

So Excel.InterOp works fine.